# Try - catch() not catching errors and throwing it instead

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, try-catch, httprequest

I have a method in a class that is supposed to only throw error log messages and then another method in another function that will get this errors and console them (for now).

The problem is that it just throws the error in the console and not in an upper level...

This are the methods from `file1.ts`:

```
private sendToApp2(App2Url: string, logObject: object) {
    try
    {
        let uriOptions = {
            host: this.hostname,
            port: this.port,
            path: '/App2',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Api-version': '1'
            }
        };

       this.App2Call(uriOptions, JSON.stringify(logObject));
    }
    catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}

private App2Call(params: Object, data: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            let req = http.request(params, (response) => {
                response.on('data', (data) => {
                    resolve(data);
                });

            }).on('error', (err: Error) => {
                reject(new Error(err.message));
            });

            req.write(data);
            req.end();
        }
        catch (err) {
            reject(new Error(err.message));
        }
    });
}
```

And in the second file, I do this logic to catch the error and console it:

```
GetErrors() {
        try {
            // initialize the class object    

            let getErrors = new FirstClass();
            await getErrors.sendToApp2(this.App2Url, this.logObject);
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without `await`, the promise rejection doesn't become an exception that you can `catch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a simple case of having forgotten to use `async` on the definition of `sendToApp2`. Since it's not `async`, there are no errors thrown during `sendToApp2` since it returns before the promise from `App2Call` rejects.

Where you're using `sendToApp2` you're using `await`, which suggests you're expecting it to return a promise, so just add `async` to the definition:

```
private async sendToApp2(App2Url: string, logObject: object) {
//      ^^^^^
```

Then the `try`/`catch` can handle rejections as errors.

---

Side note: Right now, there's no point to the `try`/`catch` in `sendToApp2`, since all it does is `throw err`.

Comment: Yep, thanks! :) An async/await was just what i needed

Answer (score 0):

return a promise from the sendToApp2 and deal with the errors when you call the function

```
private sendToApp2(App2Url: string, logObject: object) {
        let uriOptions = {
            host: this.hostname,
            port: this.port,
            path: '/App2',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Api-version': '1'
            }
        };

       return this.App2Call(uriOptions, JSON.stringify(logObject));
}
etErrors.sendToApp2(this.App2Url, this.logObject).then(
     function(){},
     function(err){ //error callback,or you can use catch();
       alert(err);
});
```